# Is there a fast way to count occurrences of items in a matrix and save them in another matrix without using loops?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a time-series matrix X whose first column contains user ID and second column contains the item ID they used at different times:

```
X=[1 4
  2 1
  4 2
  2 3
  3 4
  1 1
  4 2
  5 3
  2 1
  4 2
  5 4];
```

I want to find out which user used which item how many times, and save it in a matrix Y. The rows of Y represent users in ascending order of ID, and the columns represent items in ascending order of ID:

```
Y=[1    0   0   1
   2    0   1   0
   0    0   0   1
   0    3   0   0
   0    0   1   1]
```

The code I use to find matrix Y uses 2 `for` loops which is unwieldy for my large data:

```
no_of_users = size(unique(X(:,1)),1);
no_of_items = size(unique(X(:,2)),1);
users=unique(X(:,1));
Y=zeros(no_of_users,no_of_items);

for a=1:size(A,1)
    for b=1:no_of_users
        if X(a,1)==users(b,1)
            Y(b,X(a,2)) = Y(b,X(a,2)) + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Is there a more time efficient way to do it?

Comment: It looks like a job for [accumarray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html). Sorry I can't be of more help right now

Comment: like @Benoit_11 suggested, it is a simple matter of accumarray(X)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[sparse](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) creates a sparse matrix from row/column indices, conveniently accumulating the number of occurrences if you give a scalar value of 1. Just convert to a full matrix.

```
Y = full(sparse(X(:,1), X(:,2), 1))

Y =

   1   0   0   1
   2   0   1   0
   0   0   0   1
   0   3   0   0
   0   0   1   1
```

But it's probably quicker to just use [accumarray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) as suggested in the comments:

```
>> Y2 = accumarray(X, 1)

Y2 =

   1   0   0   1
   2   0   1   0
   0   0   0   1
   0   3   0   0
   0   0   1   1
```

(In Octave, `sparse` seems to take about 50% longer than `accumarray`.)

Comment: nice one :D but I still think accumarray is faster, but mb I'm wrong

Comment: @GameOfThrows It very well could be, but since you guys claimed `accumarray`, I went with `sparse` ;)

Comment: @GameOfThrows added.